# How to get product id from a loop using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am building a shopping cart. I want to get the product Id of each product in the loop but I just get the first product id

Code update *

```
@if(Session::has('shopping_cart'))
    @foreach(Session::get('shopping_cart') as $item)
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$item['code']}}" id="product_id">
        <div class="row mt-3 pb-3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
                <select name="qty" id="qty" data-product-id="{{$item['code']}}">
                    @for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
                    <option <?php if($item["quantity"]== $i) echo "selected";?> value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                    @endfor
                </select>
        </div>

        <?php $total_price += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]); ?>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The javascript that gets the the product id

```
const qtys = document.querySelectorAll('#qty');

for(const qty of qtys){
    qty.addEventListener('change', changeTheQuantity);
    var product_ids = $(this).data('product_id');
    console.log(product_ids);
}
// add_to_cart.addEventListener('click', addToCart);
for(const qty of qtys){
    qty.addEventListener('change', changeTheQuantity);

    var product_ids = $(this).data('product_id');
    console.log(product_ids);
}

function changeTheQuantity(e){
    var qty_val = $(this).val();
    var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
        });
        var data = {qty_val, product_id, _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}'};
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/products/cart/update-cart',
            data:data,
            success:function(data){
                console.log('success')
               console.log(data.total);
               $('#total').text(data.total);
            }

        });

}
```

I updated my code thanks. I have tried everything that I can but it not yet working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-writing the same DOM element, `id`, with the same `id` over and over, in this line, which is inside a loop for carts:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$item['code']}}" id="product_id">
```

Then, when you go to retrieve this value with jQuery in this line:

```
var product_id = $('#product_id').val();
```

it doesn't know which `#product_id` to pull from because there could be more than one.  You have the same problem with the `#qty` select box - it is also inside the shopping cart loop and thus may have multiple selects assigned with the same `id`.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove those ids from the elements where it is repeated (add a class if you wish).  Then add the critical data that you need (`product_id`) to whatever element is calling `changeTheQuantity()`.  So, if your select is calling `changeTheQuantity()`, you may add something like this:

```
 <select name="qty[]" data-product-id="{{$item['code']}}">
```

And then in your jQuery method:

```
 var product_id = $(this).data('product-id');
```

You can then remove the line with hidden input at the top of this answer.

**EDIT**: To make it a little more clear -- remove hidden, make ID on select a class, make name unique by adding the product id to it:

```
@foreach(Session::get('shopping_cart') as $item)
    <div class="row mt-3 pb-3" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
            <select name="qty{{$item['code']}}" class="qty" data-product-id="{{$item['code']}}">
                @for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
                <option <?php if($item["quantity"]== $i) echo "selected";?> value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
                @endfor
            </select>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

On the jQuery side, let's get the right object by using the **class** as a selector, not an `id` that has been re-used:

```
$(".qty").on("change", function () {
    var qty_val = $(this).val();
    // NOTE we are drawing from data for the id, and use the '-' to select
    var product_id = $(this).data('product-id');
   // AJAX, etc
 }
```

Comment: I tried it but it is getting a null. Can you please check my update.

Comment: Sure - I've edited to hopefully help make it more clear